# How to use returned result set value in other java file?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public execute_query(String Query)
{
    Resultset rs = smt.executeQuery();
    return (rs); //something like this
}
```

I have an `execute_query` function in separate java file wherein I have returned resultset reference variable. Now how to use this rs in another java file?

Comment: Don't do this. Transform the result and return the result of the transformation. Result sets have their lifetime bound to the statement and connection, and returning them to something without control over the statement and connection is bound to give you a lot of bugs related to the object lifetime. Your API as shown also just (badly) wraps the statement API, that does not add any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to tell the function to return a ResultSet by doing

> public ResultSet execute_query

and then in the other file you do

> private queryClass object = new QueryClass();
>   ResultSet newResultSet = object.executeQuery(query);